# Do not change keyword when marking repeating tasks as DONE

Tags: org-mode, keywords

I defined RECURRING as a special keyword for tasks that are repeated periodically.
When I mark the task as done with C-c C-t d the keyword switches to the default TODO keyword. I want it however to keep the RECURRING keyword. How to achieve this?

Minimal example:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t!) RECURRING(R!) | DONE(d!)
#+STARTUP: logdrawer
#+STARTUP: indent

# Task before marking it as done with C-c C-t d 
* RECURRING go shopping 
SCHEDULED: <2023-06-07 Wed ++7d>
:LOGBOOK:
- State "RECURRING"  from              [2023-06-07 Wed 12:49]
:END:

# Task after marking it as done with C-c C-t d
# Keyword changed to TODO 
* TODO reply mail 
DEADLINE: <2023-06-18 Sun ++7d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2023-06-07 Wed 13:00]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 13:00]
- State "RECURRING"  from              [2023-06-07 Wed 12:49]
:END:
```

I could define the keywords in the following order, to prevent this behaviour: `#+TODO: RECURRING(R!) TODO(t!) | DONE(d!)`
After marking the task as done, the keyword is reset to RECURRING.
However, I don't like this 'hack' because I sometimes use Shift+Rightarrowkey on a heading without a keyword and want the TODO state to appear first. Otherwise the log will save RECURRING as first state, although the task was never meant to be a recurring task. See the following example:

```
#+TODO: RECURRING(R!) TODO(t!) | DONE(d!)
#+STARTUP: logdrawer
#+STARTUP: indent

* TODO task with previously no keyword, cycling with Shift+Rightarrowkey
:LOGBOOK:
- State "TODO"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 13:09]
- State "RECURRING"  from              [2023-06-07 Wed 13:08]
:END:
```

Comment: Have you read [TODO Extensions](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Extensions.html) in the manual? In particular, how exactly did you define `RECURRING`? You might want to look into the subsections [Multiple sets in one file](https://orgmode.org/manual/Multiple-sets-in-one-file.html) and [Per file keywords](https://orgmode.org/manual/Per_002dfile-keywords.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NickD. I added a minimal example of my setup and more explanation. I also had a look at the manual again, but could not find a solution to my problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a footnote in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html#FOOT69).

It says:

> In fact, the target state is taken from, in this sequence, the ‘REPEAT_TO_STATE’ property, the variable org-todo-repeat-to-state if it is a string, the previous TODO state if org-todo-repeat-to-state is t, or the first state of the TODO state sequence.

So in the example above you could use a property, perhaps setting it up in a capture template to achieve the desired behavior or you could just set the following in the emacs configuration: `(setq org-todo-repeat-to-state "RECURRING")`

The minimal example from above is then:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t!) RECURRING(R!) | DONE(d!)
#+STARTUP: logdrawer
#+STARTUP: indent

# using property 
* RECURRING go shopping 
:PROPERTIES:
:REPEAT_TO_STATE: RECURRING
:LAST_REPEAT: [2023-06-07 Wed 14:23]
:END:
SCHEDULED: <2023-06-21 Wed ++7d>
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 14:23]
- State "DONE"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 14:23]
- State "RECURRING"  from              [2023-06-07 Wed 12:49]
:END:

# using (setq org-todo-repeat-to-state "RECURRING") in emacs configuration 
* RECURRING reply mail 
DEADLINE: <2023-07-02 Sun ++7d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2023-06-07 Wed 14:19]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 14:19]
- State "DONE"       from "RECURRING"  [2023-06-07 Wed 14:19]
- State "RECURRING"  from              [2023-06-07 Wed 14:19]
:END:
```